# ${CHANGES} does not work in the mail-ext plugin if jenkins job is driven by a bash script

Tags: version-control, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have setup a Jenkins job to build a project. I'm using email-ext plugin to send out build notifications with the intent of showing who did what and the path to the files changed. But unfortunately I'm not getting anything. I believe the reason why is that under "Source Code Management" I'm setting it to "None". My shell script that I'm using to drive the build is responsible for check-in out a copy of the code based on a CVS tag and run maven to do the build. In the ext-email i'm using the following syntax

```
${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS, reverse=true, showPaths=true,
format="\n====\nChanges for Build # %n\n%c\n",
changesFormat="\n[%r] %d %a %m %p\n"}
```

Same thing with `CHANGES`:  `${CHANGES, showPaths=true}`

Is there a way of getting `CHANGES` and `CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS` to work if `None` option is used under Source Code Management?

Thanks for your help folks.

Answer (score 2):

EmailExt plugin gets that info from Jenkins. As Jenkins has access to that info only via its SCM plugins the answer is "no", you can't do it without specifying the SCM option.

There are two things you can do:

(1) Do it by hand. Which with CVS, if I remember correctly, means having a working copy checked out anyway.
(2) Use SCM checkout/update option, but store the working copy on the side without using it in the build. You'll use twice as much disk-space, but nowadays disk-space is not a problem.

By the way, why are you using CVS? SVN, GIT, and Mercurial are all free.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Scott. That's what i've been using to get around this limitation. As far as CVS goes? Don't get me started please....It's a long story but....One more question since we're at tho...  Is it possible to pass the Module(s) (content of the txt box) under CVS (source Code Management) as an ENV  variable to the shell script? I tried that but it does not seem to work. What about parameters entered by a user during the build? I would like to pass them to the Module(s) section and then checkout the source based on this param. Is there a workaround? So far nothing is working for me.....

Comment: @jenniferBrown, are you using EnvInject plugin to pass your environment variables around? Anything short of that most probably won't work. See the following answers for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10626193/1178189, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10430129/1178189, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10415311/1178189, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10715705/1178189,
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10626180/1178189